# Converting .Xcodeproj file to .Apf file

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am developing a game in xcode using cocos2d-x i want to convert the .xcodeproj file to .apk file for that i use the Stella SDK. after download the package I try to configure it. But i am getting the following error, I typed in terminal.Please help me.

```
mac-man:~ srikanthreddy$ cd / opt
mac-man:/ srikanthreddy$ git clone https://github.com/morningtec/StellaSDK.git
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'StellaSDK'.: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to clone the git project into /opt which is a directory that you may not have write permission for.

Usually you'd create such projects in your home directory, so try this instead:

```
mkdir ~/StellaSDK
cd ~/StellaSDK
git clone https://github.com/morningtec/StellaSDK.git
```

Note that this step is only cloning the StellaSDK project, it has nothing to do with the task you described (creating an .apk file). From that I take it you haven't fully understood that StellaSDK is a game engine / framework just like cocos2d-x, so you can't use that to create an .apk file unless you start a new project. In particular you can't just convert a .xcodeproj to work with Stella SDK, there is no automatism like that.

While at the same time cocos2d-x is a cross-platform engine capable of creating Android .apk apps. The reason why you're trying to use Stella for (or in place of?) an already existing cocos2d-x project is a bit of a mystery to me.